# Checkbox selected bind with TableView

Tags: javafx

How to bind with TableView selection model [image]with checkbox isSelected in table view.In manually (using mouse multiple select) select the item in tableview

```
 ObservableList<T> observableList = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
 System.out.println(observableList);
```

how to bind checkbox with tableview

```
   box.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                                if (t1) {
                                    Object object = getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex());
                                    objects.add(object);
                                    getTableView().getItems().set(getTableRow().getIndex(), object);
                                    tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();                                    //tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(getTableRow().getIndex());

                                } else {
                                    Object object = getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex());
                                    objects.remove(object);
                                }
                                System.out.println(objects);
                            }
                        });
```

if Checkbox is selected in row that row item bind with `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` or how set manually setSelectedItems in tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to this line in `box.selectedProperty().addListener()`

`tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());`

```
box.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
        if (t1) {
            tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());

        } else {
            tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(getTableRow().getIndex());
        }
    }
});
```