# JavaFX TableView Custom selection model

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table view with a custom cell factory to have a checkbox.
I want to bind selection between a checkbox and a selected row. ( select a row manually)

The problems are

1) I can't manage to get the row when a change occurs, I can get a cell index that doesn't correspond to anything.

2) If I manually select index 0, it does a strange selection ( grey vs blue, different then when you click)

Comment: Can you paste you code or send a screenshot or your application?

Comment: Here is my CellFactory:

http://eugeneciurana.com/pastebin/pastebin.php?show=46392

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox selected bind with TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402124/checkbox-selected-bind-with-tableview)

Comment: Hello, I have tried a different solution, and it doesn't work properly, mostly because the current selection model clears stuff on click.